# Query about Satellite Thermal Imaging

Tags: landsat, landsat-8

I am working on my undergraduate thesis and for this I need access to Satellite Thermal Imagery. I have spent some time looking at how to get these Images. I know from my investigation in the last 1 week that Landsat 7 and 8 provide datasets for this. I have a few questions regarding the same :-

1. How to download and view the thermal datasets in the first place. I could not find an online tool which allows you to obtain thermal images coming from these satellites?
2. I know from Wikipedia that combining datasets from Landsat 7 and 8, I can get access to data which is updated every 8 days. Are there any other public satellites which combined to these would reduce the number of days in which a updated scene can be obtained?

Comment: Have you read https://gisgeography.com/usgs-earth-explorer-download-free-landsat-imagery/?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

The best location for finding Landsat data is on the [NASA EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/).
On the first tab, you indicate where your study site is located.
On the second tab, you locate Landsat and choose Landsat 7 & 8, either Level 1 or 2. Level 1 is the raw data, Level 2 is atmospherically corrected. There may be a delay on accessing Level 2 data.
On the last tab, you download the results that you need.

As for the second part of your question - you can just download both datasets from the site mentioned above, but there are data quality issues related to the later parts of the Landsat 7 data series.

From there, it is just a matter of using the data in a good way, but that is a different question for another SE post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try apps from ESRI for Landsat http://landsatexplorer.esri.com/ and for Sentinel2 https://sentinel2explorer.esri.com/